# How can I use an external library locally?

Tags: java, maven

I made some changes in an external library and that library I use it in my project. 
I could not released the new changes for that library because I had some problems with Jenkins.

How can I access locally those new changes from that library in my project ? In order to not wait until the Jenkins it is fix.

Comment: do you use a dependency management system?

Comment: Yes, I use maven

Comment: that's how. but what do you mean "I made some changes in an external library"?

Comment: <com.library.version>1.0.75</com.library.version>

Comment: I depend on this library, and I needed to do some changes on it. Because my project depend on this, I want to access the new changes in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your new snapshot dependency in local `clean install` .

This will deploy the new snapshot in your local maven repository.

The dependency has a snapshot version. For snapshots, Maven will check the local repository and if the artifact found in the local repository is too old, it will attempt to find an updated one in the remote repositories. That is probably what you are seeing.